# Get attributes from non-overlapping points and polygons

Tags: python, pandas, geospatial, qgis, geopandas

I have two geodatasets -- one is in points (centroids from a different polygon, let's name it **point_data**) and the other one is a polygon of a whole country (let's name it **polygon_data**). What I'm trying to do now is to get attributes from polygon_data and put them in point_data. But the problem is that they are not overlapping with each other.

To better understand the context, the country is archipelagic by nature, and the points are outside the country (that's why they're not overlapping).

Some solutions that I've tried are:

1.) Buffer up polygon_data so that it would touch point_data. Unfortunately this caused problems because the shapes that are not in the shoreline also buffered up.

2.) Used the original polygon of point_data and did a `spatial join` (intersects), but the problem is that there are some points that still returned with `null` values and duplicate rows also occured.

I want to make the process as seamless and easy as possible. Any ideas?

I'm both proficient with geopandas and qgis, but I would prefer it in geopandas as much as possible.

Thank you to whoever will be able to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try to join your data depending on the distance between the points and the polygon(s). By doing so, you can fetch the index of the nearest polygon feature for each of your points, then use this index to do the jointure.

To replicate your problem, I generated a layer of points and a layer of polygons (they have an attribute `name` that I want to put on the point layer).

[image]

One (naive) way to do so could be the following:

```
# read the polygon layer and the point layer
poly_data = gpd.read_file('poly_data.geojson')
pt_data = gpd.read_file('pt_data.geojson')

# Create the field to store the index
# of the nearest polygon feature
pt_data['join_field'] = 0

for idx, geom in pt_data['geometry'].iteritems():
    # Compute the distance between this point and each polygon
    distances = [
        (idx_to_join, geom.distance(geom_poly))
        for idx_to_join, geom_poly in poly_data['geometry'].iteritems()]
    # Sort the distances...
    distances.sort(key=lambda d: d[1])
    # ... and store the index of the nearest polygon feature
    pt_data.loc[(idx, 'join_field')] = distances[0][0]


# make the join between pt_data and poly_data (except its geometry column)
# based on the value of 'join_field'
result = pt_data.join(
        poly_data[poly_data.columns.difference(['geometry'])],
        on='join_field')

# remove the `join_field` if needed
result.drop('join_field', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Result: (the value in the `name` column is coming from the polygons)

```
    id                  geometry name
0    1  POINT (-0.07109 0.40284)    A
1    2   POINT (0.04739 0.49763)    A
2    3   POINT (0.05450 0.29858)    A
3    4   POINT (0.06635 0.11848)    A
4    5   POINT (0.63744 0.73934)    B
5    6   POINT (0.61611 0.53555)    B
6    7   POINT (0.76540 0.44787)    B
7    8   POINT (0.84597 0.36256)    B
8    9  POINT (0.67062 -0.36493)    C
9   10  POINT (0.54028 -0.37204)    C
10  11  POINT (0.69194 -0.60900)    C
11  12  POINT (0.62085 -0.65166)    C
12  13  POINT (0.31043 -0.48578)    C
13  14  POINT (0.36967 -0.81280)    C
```

Depending on the size of your dataset you may want to consider more efficient methods (e.g. defining a maximum search radius around each point to avoid having to iterate across all polygons).

Comment: Hi! Thank you for this. I will try to do this in python. But meanwhile, I was able to solve this by using `Join attributes by nearest` from QGIS. It solved my use case. Thank you again for answering! :)